# Localization url redirect issue

Tags: isapi-rewrite

We are toying around with localization at the moment

www.somesite.com : Just normal
www.somesite.com/de/ : Should redirect to www.somesite.com?lang=de

Same for sub pages.

www.somesite.com/de/someCategory.html : should redirect to www.somesite.com/someCategory.html?lang=de

And finally

www.somesite.com/de/someCategory/SomeProduct.html : Should redirect to www.somesite.com/someCategory/SomeProduct.html?Lang=de

Any on how to get starts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w{2})(/.*)?$ (?2$2:/)\?lang=$1 [QSA]
```